# Problem with gunicorn and nginx while deploying django project to digitalocean

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I am trying to host a django project using digitalocean on a domain. While the project is visible in the ip address, it does not work with the domain. These are the exact steps I tried. Can you please help sort this issue. Thank you.

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev nginx
3. sudo pip3 install virtualenv
4. mkdir ~/projectdir and cd~/projectdir
5. source env/bin/activate
6. pip install django gunicorn
7. django-admin startproject test_project ~/projectdir
8. ~/projectdir/manage.py makemigrations
9. ~/projectdir/manage.py migrate
10. sudo ufw allow 8000
11. sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
12. gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /home/MY_USER_NAME/projectdir/test_project test_project.wsgi
13. deactivate
14. sudo vim /etc/systemcd/system/gunicorn.socket
15. Pasted the following content by using vim:

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

16. sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
17. Pasted the following content through vim:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=MY_USER_NAME
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/MY_USER_NAME/projectdir
ExecStart=/home/MY_USER_NAME/projectdir/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          test_project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

18. sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
19. sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
20. sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/test_project/
21. Pasted the following content using vim:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name IP_ADDRESS www.MY_DOMAIN  MY_DOMAIN;
     location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
     location /static/ {
         root /home/MY_USER_NAME/projectdir;
     }
     location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
     }
}
```

22. sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test_project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
23. sudo systemctl restart nginx

I tried debugging the issue by running `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`. I get the following message:

```
× gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-01-11 15:57:45 UTC; 10min ago
TriggeredBy: × gunicorn.socket
    Process: 22861 ExecStart=/home/odin/projectdir/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfil>
   Main PID: 22861 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 272ms

gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

Here is the project structure:

```
home/
  USER_NAME/
    projectdir/
      env/
      test_project/
        test_project/
          wsgi.py/
```

Comment: Have you checked gunicorn logs?

Comment: Also, if it might be helpful, I am getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_project.wsgi' when I run sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.service

Comment: Mirodil, yes, I just did and I get the above error

Comment: It seems, you pointed wrong path in your gunicorn.service

Comment: As you can see in step 12, I changed the directory to point to the wsgi file. Now, when I update the gunicorn.service file by using the following code, it does not work:

WorkingDirectory=/home/USERNAME/projectdir
ExecStart=/home/USERNAME/projectdir/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind run/gunicorn.sock \
          --chdir /home/USERNAME/projectdir/test_project
          test_project.wsgi:application

Comment: can you share project structure tree?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the original post including the project structure

Comment: Not sure how you ended up with a `test_project` directory within another `test_project` directory, but since you have, you might try to change the `ExecStart` end of your **gunicorn.service** from `test_project.wsgi:application` to `test_project/test_project.wsgi:application`